# htaccess Redirect or Rewrite URL - adding a segment to the URL without causing an infinite loop

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL that I need to add a segment `/#!/` to.

This isn't working because I get a loop.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch "/constantsegment/(.*)" "/constantsegment/#!/$1"
```

For example, let's say my URL is `http://example.com/constantsegment/changeablesegment`. I need the site to redirect to `http://example.com/constantsegment/#!/changeablesegment`.

Notice that there is a URL segment(folder) called `#!` in between `constantsegment` and `changeablesegment`.

The problem I am running into is that a redirect loop is created when trying to append `/#!/` to the `/constantsegment/`. How can I just added `/#!/` to the end and then add all the other segment(s) after that.

Again

```
http://example.com/constantsegment/changeablesegment
```

Should redirect to

```
http://example.com/constantsegment/#!/changeablesegment
```

Another example (in this case products is the constant segment)

```
http://example.com/products/cars/blue
```

Should redirect to

```
http://example.com/products/#!/cars/blue
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> RedirectMatch "/constantsegment/(.*)" "/constantsegment/#!/$1"
> ```

Simply change `.*` to `.+` (1 or more) to avoid matching the target URL and causing a redirect loop. Because the fragment identifier is not passed back to the server on the redirected request.

You can avoid repetition by capturing the first "constant" path segment as well. For example:

```
RedirectMatch "/(constantsegment)/(.+)" "/$1/#!/$2"
```

Note that the above mod_alias directive (ie. `RedirectMatch`) has nothing to do with mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteEngine On`). And neither is `Options FollowSymLinks` required here. Unless you are using mod_rewrite elsewhere in your `.htaccess` file.

If you are already using mod_rewrite for other redirects then you should probably use mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule`) instead (to avoid unexpected conflicts). For example:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(constantsegment)/(.+) /$1/#!/$1 [NE,R,L]
```

The `NE` flag is required to prevent the `#` (hash) being URL encoded and considered part of the URL-path.

Note that all these redirects are 302 (temporary).

Comment: This is great explanation, very nice for new learners thank you for sharing, cheers.